# How to find the value of a named attribute within the closest div to my element?

Tags: jquery

In my jquery script I want to first match all image elements, so I'm doing this successfully:

```
$("img")
```

Now I need to get the value of the `data-context-item-id` attribute that is contained in a parent div. Here's an actual block:

```
<div class="yt-lockup clearfix  yt-lockup-video yt-lockup-grid vve-check" data-context-item-id="zBpS7_GgvTs" data-visibility-tracking="CCsQlDUiEwitlY7EmpLRAhUFgU4KHYLMBDwomxxAu_qCjf_dlI3MAQ==">
   <div class="yt-lockup-dismissable">
      <div class="yt-lockup-thumbnail">
         <span class=" spf-link  ux-thumb-wrap contains-addto">
            <a href="/watch?v=zBpS7_GgvTs" class="yt-uix-sessionlink" aria-hidden="true" data-sessionlink="ei=pzthWO2lKoWCugKCmZPgAw&amp;feature=c4-videos-u&amp;ved=CEsQlx4iEwitlY7EmpLRAhUFgU4KHYLMBDwomxw">  <span class="video-thumb  yt-thumb yt-thumb-196">
            <span class="yt-thumb-default">
            <span class="yt-thumb-clip">
            <img width="196" aria-hidden="true" data-ytimg="1" alt="" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/zBpS7_GgvTs/hqdefault.jpg?custom=true&amp;w=336&amp;h=188&amp;stc=true&amp;jpg444=true&amp;jpgq=90&amp;sp=68&amp;sigh=qu9lcW3e2YYrWP8nChAGopv3wL4" onload=";__ytRIL(this)" style="display: none;">
...more here...
```

Notice the top-post div containing the attribute named `data-context-item-id`. I need to obtain that value (in this case it's `zBpS7_GgvTs`), beginning from the selector of `img`.

There will be many of these on a page so I need to do an `each()`. I need to get a handle to the DIV containing that attribute, and also I need the attribute's value. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.each()` method and `closest()` :

```
$("img").each(function(){
     $(this).closest('div[data-context-item-id]').data('context-item-id');
})
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$("img").each(function(){
  console.log( $(this).closest('div[data-context-item-id]').data('context-item-id') );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-context-item-id="zBpS7_GgvTs111111">
  <img width="196" aria-hidden="true" data-ytimg="1" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/q/I/h/c/C/number-1-design-th.png"/>
</div>

<div data-context-item-id="zBpS7_GgvTs222222">
  <img width="196" aria-hidden="true" data-ytimg="1" alt="" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/R/q/f/z/C/C/2-in-circle-th.png"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$("img").each(function(){
    console.log($(this).parents().('div[data-context-item-id]').data('context-item-id'));
});
```